# How to expose status of all service running within Docker images under Docker ps status column/ custome column

Tags: docker, logging, config.json

I want to get status of all my services running within docker image while building docker container in Docker ps status column
Example while ulploading data into database so I get status of data uploading into db in docker ps status column or custom column.

Comment: Docker doesn't have any facility for containers to publish status or data back to the Docker daemon.  You'd need to implement this using some other monitoring system or orchestrator.

Comment: Kindly tell me on that the working of HEALTHCHECK which tells us on 'docker ps' command that the container is healthy or not. Correspondingly Any other method to insert our custom string on the place of healthy message showing on docker ps.

Comment: It is our requirement so how can I achieve this. Kindly help me out.